# "Subquery returned more than 1 value" when combining tables with subquery

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables from these first two queries that I'm trying to combine into one to show the total number of suppliers and total number of consumers by state.

I'm hoping to do it using a subquery, but I can't figure out how to use the GROUP BY statement and not get the "subquery returned more than one value" error. Any advice on the third query would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT State, COUNT(Supp_ID) Suppliers
FROM Tb_Supplier
GROUP BY State;

SELECT State, COUNT(Con_ID) Consumers
FROM Tb_Consumer
GROUP BY State;

SELECT s.State, COUNT(s.Supp_ID) Suppliers, (SELECT COUNT(c.Con_ID)
                                             FROM Tb_Consumer c
                                             GROUP BY c.State) Consumers
FROM Tb_Supplier s
GROUP BY s.State
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- I think this is easier to manage, especially if you include more counts.
-- It will include suppliers from states without consumers and 
-- consumers living in states without suppliers.


SELECT State, SUM(Suppliers) Suppliers, SUM(Consumers) Consumers
FROM (
     SELECT State, COUNT(1) Suppliers, 0 Consumers
     FROM Tb_Supplier
     GROUP BY State

     UNION ALL

     SELECT State, 0 Suppliers, COUNT(1) Consumers
     FROM Tb_Consumer
     GROUP BY State) Report
GROUP BY State
```

Answer (score 1):

correlate your subquery with `c.State = s.State`, so we can have 1 is to 1 mapping between your `supplier` and `consumer` tables

```
SELECT s.State, COUNT(s.Supp_ID) Suppliers, 
    (SELECT COUNT(c.Con_ID)
     FROM Tb_Consumer c WHERE  c.State = s.State
     GROUP BY c.State) Consumers
FROM Tb_Supplier s
GROUP BY s.State
```

another option is to use `left join`. more cleaner code.

```
SELECT s.State, COUNT(s.Supp_ID) as Suppliers, COUNT(c.Con_ID) as Consumers 
FROM Tb_Supplier s
LEFT JOIN b_Consumer c ON c.State = s.State
GROUP BY s.State
```

Comment: Both will miss counting Consumers that live in states without a supplier. Think Alaska.